# Java print array with two separators

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, separator, system.out

Hi i'm trying to get two sets of separators into on line. with my current code i get "," as my separator
the result looks like this [2,2,2,2,2]
But i am aiming to get it like this  [2,2,2,2 and 2]

```
for (int i = 0; i < intArray.length; i++) {
    if (i > 0) {
        System.out.print(", ");
    }
    System.out.print(intArray[i]);
}
```

Comment: I think `[2,2,2,2, and 2]` would be more grammatically correct (if that's what you're going for)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what you are looking for

```
public class JavaPrintArrayWithTwoSeperators {

        public static void main(String[] args) {

            int[] intArray = { 2, 2, 2, 2, 2 };
            for (int i = 0; i < intArray.length; i++) {
                if (i > 0 && i < intArray.length - 1) {
                    System.out.print(", ");
                } else if (i > intArray.length - 2) {
                    System.out.print(" and ");
                }
                System.out.print(intArray[i]);
            }
        }
    }
```

I hope it will help 
Thanks.....

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
public class Main {
  public static void main (String[]args) {
    int[] intArray = new int[]{ 2, 2, 2, 2 };
    for (int i = 0; i < intArray.length; i++) {
      if (i > 0 && i != (intArray.length - 1)) {
        System.out.print (", ");
      } 
      if (i == (intArray.length - 1)) {
          System.out.print(" and ");
      }
      System.out.print (intArray[i]);
    }
  }
}
```

Output is `2, 2, 2 and 2`

Answer (score 0):

Here's one idea

```
for(int i=0; i<intArray.length-1; i++){
    if(i>0) {
        System.out.print(", ");
    }
    System.out.print(intArray[i]);
 }
 System.out.println(" and " + intArray[intArray.length-1]);
```

Comment: My system cordinator wants it to all be innside of the int array. Like when the system hits the 4.th number it will swap out the , with an "and"